# How to document multiple return values using reStructuredText in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, documentation, restructuredtext

The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/devguide/documenting.html) say that "the markup used for the Python documentation is [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sf.net/rst.html)". My question is: How is a block comment supposed to be written to show multiple return values?

```
def func_returning_one_value():
    """Return just one value.

    :returns: some value
    :rtype: str
    """

def func_returning_three_values():
    """Return three values.

    How do I note in reStructuredText that three values are returned?
    """
```

I've found a [tutorial](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/sphinx/docstring_python.html) on Python documentation using reStructuredText, but it doesn't have an example for documenting multiple return values. The [Sphinx docs on domains](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html) talks about `returns` and `rtype` but doesn't talk about multiple return values.

Comment: Seems like anything goes with docstrings, as long as it is clear and concise and consistent throughout a project.  Write something that suits your purpose.  [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) has some broad conventions.  Look through the Python dot py files on your computer and see how the devs did it.

Comment: Like [os.walk()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a237032d7732bd9142e3802b77767d342bb30870/Lib/os.py#L277) which returns multiple things.

Answer (score 20):

There is a compromised solution: just write in normal Markdown texts.
e.g.

```py
def func(a, b):
    """

    :param int a: first input
    :param int a: second input
    :returns: 
        - x - first output
        - y - second output
    """

    return x, y
```

This will generate the following document:

[image]

Almost what we want, right?

The shortcoming for this is that you cannot specify return type for every element. You would have to write it by yourself, such as

```py
"""
:returns:
    -x (:py:class:`int`) - first output
"""
```

Answer (score 8):

As wwi mentioned in the comments, the detailed format to be used is not strictly defined.

For myself, I usually use the [Field List](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#field-lists) notation style you use above. It supports line breaks, so just break where you feel is necessary

```
def my_func(param1, param2):
    """
    This is a sample function docstring

    :param param1: this is a first param
    :param param2: this is a second param
    :returns: tuple (result1, result2) 
        WHERE
        str result1 is .... 
        str result2 is ....        
    """
```

Comment: Doesn't work with me. Do you have to install something special, or tell Sphinx that it has to use field list?